# Half Sum Element

Tags: python

Please can you help me with this exercise:

> Half Sum Element:
>
> Write a program that inputs n integers and checks whether there is a number among them, which is equal to the sum of all the rest. If there is such an element, print "Yes" + its value, otherwise print - "No" + the difference between the largest element and the sum of the rest (by absolute value).
>
> Sample Input and Output:
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 4
> 6
> 1
> 2
> 3
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> Yes 
> Sum = 6
> ```
>
> Hints and Guidelines:
> We have to calculate the sum of all elements, find the largest of them, and check the condition.

I tried:

```
import sys

max_num = -sys.maxsize
sum_numbers = 0

n = int(input())

for i in range(0, n):
    num = int(input())

for i in range(0, n):
    num = int(input())

    if num > max_num:
        max_num = num
    sum_numbers += num

if max_num == sum_numbers - max_num:
    print("Yes")
    print(f"Sum= {sum_numbers}")

else:
    print("No")
    sum_numbers = sum_numbers - max_num
    print(f"Diff= {abs(max_num - sum_numbers)}")
```

My result:
Nothing is printed

Comment: your program is interactive, so if it reaches the end you should read from the screen at least either a `Yes` or `No`. If you cannot see it, it's because you need to do a keyboard input. Try to pass a message string to it, smt like `input("Waiting for xyz")` to clarify which action you need to perform

Comment: Your output does not match the specification. You give the answer as 12 but the "sum of all the rest" is 19

Comment: Sorry, input edited.

Comment: @dstv Still wrong. 12 is not among the list of inputs. I'm guessing that the author of [this challenge](https://github.com/SoftUni/Programming-Basics-Book-CSharp-EN/blob/master/Content/Chapter-5-1-loops/exercises-loops/half-sum-element.md) does not have English as her first language

Comment: you don't need two for loops. after the first loop there are no numbers left to be processed.

Comment: _"program that inputs n integers"_ — how is `n` determined?  It's not clear from the question.

Comment: _'print "Yes" + its value'_ — check what you actually `print`

Comment: Sorry, input and output edited .

Comment: Also: you code assumes non-negative sum.

Comment: That first `for` loop is useless. You don't do anything with the values. Delete those two lines and you'll get output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a Q&A site, but there's no question here and it's not really clear what you need help with since your code has a mistake that seems to be obvious (two loops). In the future, please make an effort to understand what your code is doing before posting. See [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341), [mre], and [How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](/q/4929251/4518341) See also [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have a logic issue in your code. You're overwriting the value of num within the loop.

I fixed the code for you and added message strings to your awaiting input to clarify which action the user should perform next.

```
import sys

max_num = -sys.maxsize
sum_numbers = 0

n = int(input("Enter iterations: "))

for i in range(0, n):
    num = int(input("Enter number: "))

    if num > max_num:
        max_num = num
    sum_numbers += num

if max_num == sum_numbers - max_num:
    print("Yes")
    print(f"Sum = {max_num}")

else:
    print("No")
    print(f"Diff = {abs(max_num - (sum_numbers - max_num))}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
n = int(input("N: "))

nums = []

for _ in range(n):
    v = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    nums.append(v)

nums.sort()

m = nums[-1]
s = sum(nums[:-1])

if m == s:
    print("Yes", m)
else:
    print("No", abs(m-s))
```

**Examples:**

```
N: 4
Enter an integer: 6
Enter an integer: 1
Enter an integer: 2
Enter an integer: 3
Yes 6

N: 4
Enter an integer: 8
Enter an integer: 3
Enter an integer: 2
Enter an integer: 1
No 2
```

**Note:**

Inputs are not validated